# A separate php script that executes jobs from beanstalkd queue. Needs access to cakephp app

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, beanstalkd

I am using beanstalkd to queue jobs.

I have a php script written inside my `app/Lib/Queue/Beanstalk/workers/DownloadFileWorker.php`

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config.php');
class DownloadS3FilesWorker extends PHPQueue\Worker
{
/**
 * @var \PHPQueue\Backend\FS
 */
    static private $dataSource;
    public $factory = null;
    private $queueConfig = array();
    private $queueBackend = 'Beanstalkd';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->queueConfig  = EPubConfig::getConfig($this->queueBackend);
        self::$dataSource = \PHPQueue\Base::backendFactory($this->queueBackend, $this->queueConfig);
    }

    /**
     * @param \PHPQueue\Job $jobObject
     */
    public function runJob($jobObject)
    {
        parent::runJob($jobObject);
        $jobData = $jobObject->data;
        App::uses('FileFactory', 'Lib/File');
        $this->factory = new FileFactory($jobData); 
        $this->factory->downloadAllFiles();
        $this->result_data = $jobData;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App' not found in /var/virtual/someapp/Lib/Queue/Beanstalk/workers/DownloadFileWorker.php on line 27
```

The `FileFactory` itself will use many other Cake related classes.

Comment: I've seen a lot of people really jumping at RabbitMQ lately. Even MarkStory, a core contributor of CakePHP talked about it at the 2011 CakeFest: https://github.com/markstory/cakefest-rabbitmq

There is probably more documentation, and community support around it. Just a thought, and good luck!

Comment: thank you @alairock I will look at it closer. Just a quick question, which one have you tried before?

Comment: @alairock having reviewed this http://www.quora.com/Beanstalk-work-queue/What-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-Beanstalkd-as-a-work-queue I think I will settle on beanstalk since I am really using a workqueue rather than a message queue

Comment: sorry for the late response (traveling the last couple days). We are actually actively using RabbitMQ to start jobs on multiple daemon servers. It works very nicely, and is fairly simple to configure and setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote as a Shell under Console/Command.

Problem solved!